# Throttle read/writes in firestore without sacrificing Svelte reactivity

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I'm building a mortgage calculator.

I have a Purchase Price field and a Down Payment field. Both have a range slider. The calculator presents the Dollar Amount (reactively) while you adjust *either* the purchase price *or* the down payment.

I have Firestore on the backend but sending input updates from the range slider to Firestore could get costly really quick.

Is there a way to throttle reads/writes with Firestore without sacrificing the reactive nature of Svelte on the front-end?

I'm imagining a Svelte store between the View and Firestore but how would you sync the Svelte store and Firestore?

It's more complicated than just a mortgage calculator, I just thought it was a great analogy.

Also, I *do* need the data to persist per user if they were to revisit later.

Comment: How crucial is it that the user sees the same values on the next visit / the last values are definitely saved? Is this just like a service to the user or do you want the values for analytics or are they important for an ordering process?

Comment: You could create a custom store which sets the value and debounces the database update

Comment: @Corrl - I've updated my post. I do need that persistence.

Comment: @Tonton-Blax - So does the Firestore only stand to _initialize_ / hydrate the Store? Does any of the view data rely on Firestore directly at all? This is coming together for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented a solution suggested by @Tonton-Blax.

I added a Custom Store that included a function that updates my Firestore database. Then I just wrapped that in a debounce.

See [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b7b4535507de4e268837abd2272a0cd3?version=3.44.2)

Custom Stores: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-stores

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the `change` event of the range input?
While the slider is dragged the current value is reactively displayed. But only when the handle is released the change event is triggered and the set value can be saved to firestore  > [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a4f5240567cd479eb9e06bab9da37c84?version=3.44.1)

```html
<script>
    let value="30"
    
    function handleOnChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value)
        //save value to firestore   
    }
</script>

<p>
    {value}
</p>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" bind:value on:change={handleOnChange}>
```

Comment: I ended up using a custom store to handle updates via the `change` event as well as update Firestore on the back end (albeit, debounced).

Thanks!

Comment: @drupalphil since I'm using firestore as well, I'd be interested in seeing your solution